# How to check that the XML element has the attribute with an empty string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlxml, xquery-sql

Is there a way to check that value of an element in the XML field has an empty size using SQLXML? Consider I have the following data in the column `Conf` of the table `Test`:

```
<Conf>
  <UserData>
    <data type="str" value="" />
  </UserData>
</Conf>
```

I can check that `data` exists by using the following SQL request:

```
SELECT Test.Conf.exist('/Conf/UserData/data') FROM Test;
```

But how can I check that `data` has an empty `value`? It could be something like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Test.Conf.value('(/Conf/UserData/data/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')='' FROM Test;
```

---

My final solution is to use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Test.Conf.value('string-length(/Conf[1]/UserData[1]/data[1]/@value)', 'int') FROM Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath 1.0. `string(@someattribute)` test should return false if empty. I know nothing about SQLXML, but it will work if you can use a control sequence.

Comment: `string-length` function does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this will work.

```
SELECT Test.Conf.exist('data(/Conf/UserData/data[@value=''''])') FROM Test;
```

This checks to see if a data element with `@value = ''` exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with XPath but with TSQL syntax.

`XML.Exist` returns a BIT datatype, indicating whether it exists. SQL Server has no native BOOLEAN datatype (a real true/false).

So, your query should have been

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Test.Conf.value('(/Conf/UserData/data/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')=''
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Test;
```